# Read an XML File with Perl and write in a Textfile

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I am trying to create a Textfile with Perl. I have an XML File which needs to be read by my Perl script. And after this it has to create a Textfile. I searched a lot in the net but can't find anything. Maybe you can support me here.

This is my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Parser;

my $file = 'data.xml';
my $count = '0';
my $parser = new XML::Parser(ErrorContext => 100000000000000000);

$parser->setHandlers(Char => \&char_handler, Default => \&default_handler);

$parser->parsefile($file);

print "Found $count comments.\n";

sub default_handler {
    my ($p, $data) = @_;

    if ($data =~ /^<!--/) {
        my $line = $p->current_line;
        $data =~ s/\n/\n\t/g;
        print "$line:\t$data\n";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

This is my XML File:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
< employee>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <age>43</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <department>Operations</department>
    <city>New York</city>
    <name>David Street</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <department>Sales</department>
    <city>San Diego</city>  
< /employee>
```

When I run the Script I get following:

```
>perl print.pl

not well-formed (invalid token) at line 2, column 1, byte 23:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
< employee>
^
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>43</age>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <department>Operations</department>
        <city>New York</city>
        <name>David Street</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <department>Sales</department>
        <city>San Diego</city>
< /employee>
at /opt/GSBperl/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/i86pc-solaris-64int/XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

This not what I need. I need a File which has this format.

```
John Doe;43;M;Operations
David Street;25;M;Sales
```

Field  I don't need.

Comment: Field "city" I don't need

Comment: What you are seeing is an error message. It says your input file is not valid XML.

Comment: If you don't know enough to even stand a chance of writing a program on your own then Stack Overflow isn't the place to look for help. This isn't a free code writing service. The usual approach is to employ someone who knows what they're doing to do the work for you. There isn't another profession where you would attempt begging on line for free work.

Comment: In any case, you are starting with invalid XML data, so no one can help you.

Comment: `lib/site_perl/5.8.8` - Do yourself a favour and try using a version of Perl that isn't over ten years old!

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid XML. To be precise, your XML is "not well-formed" (as the error message says).

The problem is that `< employee>` is not a valid XML tag. You cannot have spaces in XML element names - so this should probably be `<employee>`.

I don't know where this XML file comes from, but it is not XML. You should go to whoever is supplying this file to you and ask them to ensure their XML is well-formed before sending to.

(There's another problem in your sample XML - spaces on the first line before the `<!xml ...>` declaration. But, given the error message you're getting, I think that's a typo you've made when posting your question here.)

**Update:** It isn't causing your current problem, but if you're getting the XML file fixed, you might ask them to fix the way that multiple employees are presented. I'd expect to see something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <age>43</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <department>Operations</department>
    <city>New York</city>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>David Street</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <department>Sales</department>
    <city>San Diego</city>  
  </employee>
</employees>
```

See, I now have a separate `<employee>` element for each person, and they are all under a new `<employees>` element.

All in all, it looks like your input file has been created by someone who knows nothing about XML :-)